# Word to describe when someone describes something in too much detail

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

In American psycho the main character describes how he kills and what he does when he kills in so much detail.

Comment: The "duplicate" rules out *ad nauseam* in the OP and it seems perfect here.

Answer (score 0):

An idiom exists addressing a situation such as this:

**too much information**  [TFD](http://too%20much%20information%20What%20was%20said%20is%20the%20type%20of%20information%20that%20should%20be%20kept%20private.)  abbrev TMI

> What was said is the type of information that should be kept private.

Comment: One definition of "overwrought" is (of a piece of writing or a work of art) too elaborate or complicated in design.

Another possibility is "tortuous" not direct or straightforward, as in procedure or speech; intricate; circuitous.

For your example, tortuous might be too apt.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard the phrase "over-explainer", as in "Don't get him started -- he's such an over-explainer you'll be there an hour." This is may be regional, certainly idiomatic.